# Implementation of the State Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, state-pattern

I have to implement a state machine with very basic requirement that every state pattern should have:

1. The state machine can be in any ONE state at a time.
2. The transition from X state to Y state will have different parameters than transition from Y to Z or from any other state to another one.
3. User program, which will be operating the "state machine" cannot, of-course, transition to a state which is not allowed to go to if you are on a particular state. for e.g. `stateMachine.dispenseCard()` will not work if `stateMachine.currentState()` is not `CASHACCEPTED`

I tried following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/509234/The-State-Design-Pattern-vs-State-Machine) link, but here:

1. The abstract State class needs to define all the possible states of the state machine, thus the concrete state needs to implement all the state methods. Why should the concrete state class be interested in all the other methods which transit to other states? Why not only the ones that this state transits to?

   ```
   public abstract class DoorState : DomainObject    {
   protected Door _door;
   public Door Door
   {
       get { return _door; }
       set { _door = value; }
   }
   public abstract void Close();
   public abstract void Open();
   public abstract void Break();
   public abstract void Lock();
   public abstract void Unlock();
   /// <summary>
   /// Fix simulates a repair to the Door and resets 
   /// the initial state of the door to closed.
   /// </summary>
   public void Fix()
   {
       _door.DoorState = new DoorClosedState(this);
   }}
   ```
2. Why does the State class "has a" Device which transits to different states? Shouldn't it be other way round? Like the Door should "has a" state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code that you have given actually defines a ***State*** that has all the ***Behaviors*** or the ***Context*** (Door in this example). The ***State*** defines how the ***Context*** should behave when in this state.

For example, when a `Door` is in the `DoorOpenedState` (assume it's fully open). when the method `Open()` is called to invoke the behavior of the `Door` to open, then should result in an error (invalid transition) because you cannot transition from `DoorOpenedState` to `DoorOpenedState`

The state patterns can be implemented in many different ways and the transition between states can be achieved in different ways. If you haven't read the [GOF book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), there they discuss the transition issues and possible implementations.

Here's an example of a state machine for a Vending machine. To simplify the example and concentrate on the state machine and transitions, let's say that our state machine has only noodles and it doesn't return excess money. So if a cup of noodles is 5$ and you give it 7$ it won't return 2$.

*NOTE: Since a communication between the `NoodleVendingMachine` and each state is required For simplicity I'll make these methods internal just to mark them. For a real project an additonal interface may be necessary in order to hide them from client code of `NoodleVendingMachine` and keep them inbetween the `NoodleVendingMachine` and it's states only.*

```
public class CacheStorage {

    public Cache AvailableCache { get; private set; }

    public void AddCache(Money cache) {
        AvailabletCache += cache;
    }

    public void ClearAvailableCache() {
        AvailabletCache = Money.None;
    }
}

public interface INoodleVendingMachineState {

    void TakeCache(Money money);

    Noodles DispenceNoodles();

    Money ReturnCache();
}

public class NoodleVendingMachine {

    private INoodleVendingMachineState mState;

    itnernal CacheStorage CacheStorage { get; private set; }

    public NoodlesPrice { get; private set; }

    public Money AvailableCache { get { return CacheStorage.AvailableCache; } }

    public NoodleVendingMachine() {

        NoodlesPrice = new Money(Currency.USD, 5); // 5 bucks for noodles
        CacheStorage = new CacheStorage();
        mState = new WaitingForCacheState(this);
    }

    public void TakeCache(Money money) {
        mState.TakeCache(money);
    }

    public Noodles DispenceNoodles() {
        return mState.DispenceNoodles();
    }

    public Money ReturnCache() {
        return mState.ReturnCache();
    }

    internal void TransitionTo(INoodleVendingMachineState state) {
        mState = state;
    }
}

public WaitingForCacheState : INoodleVendingMachineState {

    private NoodlesVendingMachine mVendingMachine;

    public WaitingForCacheState(NoodlesVendingMachine vendingMachine) {
        mVendingMachine = vendingMachine;
    }

    public void TakeCache(Money cache) { 

        mVendingMachine.CacheStorage.AddCache(cache);
        mVendingMachine.TransitionTo(new CacheAvailableState(mVendingMachine));
    }

    public Noodles DispenceNoodles() { 
        throw new InsertCacheFirstException();
    }

    public Money ReturnCache() {
        throw new CacheNotAvailableException();
    }
}

public CacheAvailableState : INoodleVendingMachineState {

    private CacheStorage mCacheStorage;
    private NoodleVendingMachine mVendingMachine;

    public CacheAvailableState(NoodleVendingMachine vendingMachine) {

        if (vendingMachine.AvailableCache == Money.None){
            throw new CacheNotAvailable()
        }

        mVendingMachine = vendingMachine;
        mCacheStorage = mVendingMachine.CacheStorage;
    }

    public void TakeCache(Money cache) {
         mCacheStorage.AddCache(cache);
    }

    public Noodles DispenceNoodles() {

        if(mCacheStorage.AvailableCache < mVendingMachine.NoodlesPrice) {
            throw new CacheNotEnoughtException();
        }

        mCacheStorage.ClearAvailableCache();

        mVendingMachine.TransitionTo(new WaitingForCacheState(mVendingMachine));

        return new Noodles();
    }

    public Money ReturnCache() {
        var cache = mCacheStorage.AvailableCache;
        mCacheStorage.ClearAvailableCache();
        mVendingMachine.TransitionTo(new WaitingForCacheState(mVendingMachine));
        return cache;
    }
}
```

Here we capture the *behavior* of the vending machine with *states*.

`WaitingForCacheState` will throw exceptions when `DispenceNoodles` or `ReturnCache` is called as this is invalid behavior in this state.

`WaitingForCacheState` will do a state transition to `CacheAvailableState` when the user inputs cache. When cache is available, we see that all *behaviors* are supported. When noodles are dispensed or the user ask for his money back, we make state transition to `WaitingForCacheState`.

In this example each state makes state transitions to the next appropriate state.

If you have more complex example for your state machine you probably will need to decide where to store the parameters. You can store it in the *Context* (`NoodlesVendingMachine` in our case). In this example, the money is stored in a special `CacheStorage` so that each state and the `NoodlesVendingMachine`has access to they can make decision based on it's value. when an action is performed (`DispenceNoodles` for example), the current state checks the value of the `CacheStorage` and makes a decision whether to make a transition, execute some behavior (`TakeMoney` in `CacheAvailableState`), throw error or execute behavior and then make a transition (`ReturnCache` in `CacheAvailableState`).

If necessary of course, you can store temporary state specific data in each `State` so it can make decisions based on that data without other objects knowing about it.

In this example `CacheAvailableState` can store the `AvailableCache` in it as a property. I decided to add it to the another class to show that this way multiple objects can have access to the data. Of course we need to show the `AvailableCache` to the user, so the `NoodlesVendingMachine` needs access to the available cache too.

We can also add it to the `NoodlesVendingMachine` but this will add methods and properties to the class and increase it's size. So we use the [Single-Responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and move the responsibility of storing the cache to another class. This will be especially effective if we have more data.

Comment: you have made it so detailed and complex, can't understand

Comment: The state pattern is a tricky one. That's why I gave detailed example. I'll try to summarize. The abstract State class defines all possible behaviors (not states) of the Context (the Door in your article, the VendingMachine in my example). Each State object represents how it's Context (Door, VendingMachine, StateMachine, etc) should behave when in this state. They may need to share data (CacheStorage in my example as they all need access to the money that the client has supplied and are used for state transitions, the parameters in your example that are need for state transitions).